# How to run multiple "update" statements in OLE DB Command SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Can I run below query in SSIS OLEDB command component.
{

```
DECLARE @ORDERID BIGINT = ? 
DECLARE @UPDATEDSKU VARCHAR(50) = ? 

UPDATE       DeviceHistory
SET          SKUReplacement = @UPDATEDSKU
WHERE        (OrderID = @ORDERID) 

DECLARE @ProductID as INT

Select @ProductID = ProductID from Products where ProductSKU= @UPDATEDSKU AND IsActive=1 AND ProgramID=2
```

}

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's that actual problem. How have you set the command task up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the two variable, @OrderID and @UpdatedSKU was placed incorrect.
Since it is an OLEDB command object, @UPdatedSKU should be first declared so that first parameter will be assigned to it.

```
DECLARE @UPDATEDSKU VARCHAR(50) = ? 
DECLARE @ORDERID BIGINT = ? 


UPDATE       DeviceHistory
SET          SKUReplacement = @UPDATEDSKU
WHERE        (OrderID = @ORDERID) 

DECLARE @ProductID as INT

Select @ProductID = ProductID from Products where ProductSKU= @UPDATEDSKU AND IsActive=1 AND ProgramID=2
```

}

We must follow sequence of Parameters when passing parameters in OLEDB command.